# material ui select arrow on left side

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, position

I am new to material ui I am trying to understand some things

I have a simple select component and I have two problems with it.

First I want to make the arrow icon of the select on the left side and not on the right
Second I want to color the input of the select in blue color but I only managed to color the dropdown values

[here is what I tried](https://codesandbox.io/s/lingering-sound-bb2zrx?file=/src/App.js)

any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MUI components are like packages that are made of some smaller parts. And you can change their styles by selecting their specific names in the `sx` props.
For example `"& .MuiMenuItem-root"` is for menu items, and `"& .MuiSvgIcon-root"` is for the little arrow icon of the Select.
By the way, to change the main things like the color of the whole thing, you only need to put that in the `sx`. This would be the thing you want:

```
<Select
  fullWidth
  IconComponent={ArrowDownwardIcon}
  value={selected}
  variant="outlined"
  onChange={selectionChangeHandler}
  sx={{
    backgroundColor: "red",
    "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
      right: "unset",
      left: "7px",
    },
  }}
>
```

You can learn about all these strings in [MUI api docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/select/#css) or inspecting theme in your browser developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I will have a look at the docs